# TempTable and filled with selected from Table, then display

Tags: sql, temp-tables

This is to create a temptable and fill it with selected data
the existing address table; after that I want to display the
temptable (that is select * and display it)

This is my code, but it has some glitches.
Does anyone know how to write it so it runs correctly?

```
CREATE TABLE #Address
                                (
                                AddressID int,
                                AddressLine1 nvarchar(60),
                                City nvarchar(30),
                                )
SELECT  AddressID,AddressLine1 
INTO    #Address
FROM    [Person].[Address]
WHERE   AddressLine1 LIKE '%Drive%' AND AddressID BETWEEN 400 and 1000


SELECT *
FROM
#Address
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have created the table so you have to use insert into, not select into. Generally, select into is used to create the table with data:

```
insert into #address (addressid, addressline1)
select addressid, addressline1 
from   Address 
where  AddressLine1 LIKE '%Drive%' AND AddressID BETWEEN 400 and 1000
```

Comment: It is as you say, 2315555 (funny name - sounds like a clone unit).I ran the code with your answer, and it worked seamlessly. THANK YOU